# Document with a Timeline structure

Tags: moderntimeline, timeline

I am writing a story, and i have to indicate the important moments with a timeline. I have made a sketch of what I would like to do:
[image: Sketch document]

I have seen that there are several questions regarding timeline, some refers to the Chronology package, but i do not understand how to put it in the vertical left side. Moreover, I would like to split the timeline in different lines and merge them at a certain time point. And it would be better that the timeline can be dynamically divided in the different pages.
I only managed to make with an external program the timeline and put it on the left, but obviously that force me to statically write the document.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far?